# Is there any way to batch upload files to Google Drive?

Tags: automation, upload, google-drive

I have 100 GB of files to be uploaded to Google Drive.

My internet connection is very slow, and my country has a lot of power failures, so my computer spontaneously restarts.

For downloading, I have a download manager which automatically starts the queue when computer starts and keep working day and night. However, it is difficult for me to upload files to Google Drive with Google's upload dialog box.

Is there any way to upload some folder to Drive and automatically resume from the previous stopped file so that I don't need to sit in front of computer all the time?

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the below Java-based solution - I have used it before and it has quite a few configuration options.

> http://code.google.com/p/google-docs-upload/

Comment: that page gives error